# Error while calling Linkedin api with spring-social-linkedin lib

Tags: spring-social, spring-social-linkedin

My organization had integrated Linkedin login in some of its sites and it was working fine until recently it started failing. Was using **1.0.2.RELEASE version**.
On analysing the root cause, found Linkedin api calls failed inside **getUserProfile()** method of **ProfileTemplate.java** inside **spring-social-linkedin** jar. Attaching screenshots of my debug screen for clarity. 
It is basically failing to call the Linkedin api url for fetching user profile and returning a **410 Gone** HTTP error.
Tried with quite a few versions of the jar but none seems to solve this.
I want to keep spring-social-linked library approach and find a solution around it.Tried with the newer **2.0.0.M3 version** too but same issue.

Any pointers/suggestions are welcome.

[image: debug screen]
[image: debug screen 2]

Comment: LinkedIn's V1 API will be brought offline on May 1 of this year. spring-social-linkedin [does not appear to have an implementation for V2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-linkedin/issues/74) so you'll have to use the [V2 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api)

Comment: @mdl : Thanks for the input. Yes I am aware of the May 1, 2019 deadline. But this issue has been occurring for sometime now, is there any hotfix you are aware of, for this, using spring-social-linkedin ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of